# Getting pointer to bottom of the call stack and resolving symbol by address (like dladdr) under Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, backtrace

I want to implement an analog of backtrace utility under windows in order to add this information to exception for example.

I need to capture return addresses and then translate it into symbols names.

I'm aware of StackWalk64 and of [StackWalker project](http://stackwalker.codeplex.com/) but unfortunately it has several important drawbacks:

- It is known to be very slow (the StackWalk64) and I don't want to waste much time for collecting the trace the basically can be done as fast as walking on linked list.
- The function StackWalk64 is known to be not thread safe.

I want to support only x86 and possible x86_64 architectures

Basic idea I have is following:

1. Run on stack using esp/ebp registers similarly to what GCC's `__builtin_return_address(x)`/`__builtin_frame_address(x)` doe till I reach the bottom of the stack (this is what glibc does).
2. Translate addresses to symbols
3. Demangle them.

### Problems/Questions:

1. How do I know that I reach the to of the stack? For example glibc implementation has `__libc_stack_end` so it is easy to find where to stop. Is there any analog of such thing under Windows? How can I get stack bottom address?
2. What are the analogs of dladdr functionality. Now I know that unlike ELF platform that keeps most of symbol names, PE format does not. So it should read somehow the debug information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Capturing Stack Trace: [RtlCaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Getting Symbols: Using DBG Help library (MSVC only). Key functions:

  ```
  // Initialization
  hProcess = GetCurrentProcess()
  SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS)
  SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE)
  // Fetching symbol
  SymFromAddr(...)
  ```

  Implementation can be found [there](http://cppcms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cppcms/framework/trunk/booster/lib/backtrace/src/backtrace.cpp?view=markup)

Answer (score 1):

You use `StackWalk` but resolve symbols later.

Comment: I've mentioned my problems with StackWalk function

Comment: in such case I just would not implement, it as overhead of StackWalk64 is too high, in comparison for example with walking on ebp frame pointers.

Comment: It is my experience that stackwalk is not so slow; its even used in stack snapshot sample profilers.  What you have to do however is avoid symbol lookups when collecting data; its the symbol lookups that are very expensive; so cache them, and compute them lazily, and so on.

Comment: Even if performance is not an issue, there are other problems with StackWalk - thread safety, total lack of any usable documentation (that you can actually read and not refer to 1001 3rd part samples) etc. If I have the pointer to bottom of the stack, I can do it easily on my own. So I really want to avoid this function.